# Unity 4.6 UI image blur

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, pixel-shader, unity3d-gui

Is there a way to set blur on the image in new UI on Unity 4.6?

I need normal image to become blurred or pixelized on button click.

I did try to use some free shader from asset store but it doesn't work on android phones.

Comment: To obtain a blur you will at least need OpenGL ES 2.0 on the mobile device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try making a blurred copy of the image and replacing it on button click via script.
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Image.html

Answer (score 0):

No script needed.

You should make normal image and blurred image

and make a uGUI Button.

Then, Button Component in Inspector, change "transition"

ColorTint to SpriteSwap, and attach two images.